# $\mathbf{Cat}$ the category of the categories is a category

Tags: category-theory

I'm studying this [book](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Category_Theory.html?id=-MCJ6x2lC7oC&redir_esc=y) and I'm trying to prove this assertion the author made:

[image]

The identity functor is the identity in this category, i.e., for each category $C$, $Id_C:C\to C$ is the identity functor.

I'm having troubles to prove the associativity of the composition of functors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your trouble? As it says, functor is just a _mapping_ of objects to objects and arrows to arrows, and they compose by ordinary composition of functions. Therefore, composition of functors inherits associativity because function composition is associative.

Comment: As a side not unrelated to the associativity of functors, I'm not sure I agree with this. I'm fairly certain a "category of all categories" will fall victim to a modified Russell's paradox... one can make it out safely if they work with the category of small categories, say.

Comment: Unless you're working in a set theory with a universal set, in which case you just lose the Yoneda lemma or some such :p

Comment: @HenningMakholm it's true, I didn't notice this fact.

Comment: @HenningMakholm composition of maps is associative and since functors are maps, we're done.

Comment: I think you mean the category of small categories (in a Grothendieck universe).

Comment: If Awodey wrote "the category of all categories", then he is imprecise.  The collection of all categories and functors is NOT a category. It can be called "metacategory" or "quasicategory" or a "category-in-a-larger-universe". In any case it should be distinguished from its constituent categories, otherwise it would belong to itself. This collection is better called CAT, while Cat is normally the "category of all *small* categories". All this stuff has been explained by me and others over and over on math.SE. Just search for CAT or Cat.